# Addition on Peano numbers at type level

Tags: haskell, types, peano-numbers

I have defined types for the Peano numbers

```
class Plus (n :: T) (m :: T) (r :: T) | r n -> m
instance Plus 'Zero m m
instance Plus n m r => Plus ('Succ n) m ('Succ r)
```

Now I find myself having two constraints `Plus a b c` and `Plus c d e`.

How can I define an addition operation on my class such that the compiler is able to derive `Plus a (b + d) e`?

Comment: Maybe consider using type families rather than classes, as this will circumvent the need for constraints.

Comment: There is no way to write `b+d` unless you switch to type families. Type families are much more natural for these things than multi parameter type classes with functional dependencies.

Comment: I guess you would add a new class like `class PlusAssociates a b d where associate :: Dict (Plus a b c, Plus c d e) -> exists f. Dict (Plus b d f, Plus a f e)` (use your favorite encoding of existentials); a suitable, complete collection of instances would amount to a proof that addition associates. (The compiler definitely won't derive such proofs for you.)